# Is it considered bad style to limit the allowed template arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Is it considered bad style to limit function templates to accept only a few allowed values for the template arguments?

Example:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {

typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Bar, T>::value, void>::type 
    callFuncInBar() {
        BarGetValue();
    }


typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<FooBar, T>::value, void>::type 
    callFuncInFooBar() {
        FooBarGetValue();
    }

};
```

EDIT:
My case is this:
I have two simple structs A and B which are almost similar:

```
struct A: public ICompress {
    void compress() override {
      next->compress();
    }

    ICompress *next;
};

struct B: public IDecompress {
    void decompress() override {
      next->decompress()
    }

    IDecompress *next;
};
```

My intention was to create a template that should be instantiated either as a Compressor or a Decompressor:

```
template<typename T>
struct codecomp: public T {
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<ICompress, T>::value, void>::type
    compress() {
      next->compress();
    }

typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<IDecompress , T>::value, void>::type
    decompress() {
      next->decompress();
    }

  T *next;
};
```

Comment: C++17 will have [concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)).  Before that the only possibility to select instantiations is SFINAE (as in your question).

Comment: @HenriMenke No, C++17 will not have concepts.

Comment: Short answer: no.   If you have a template that makes sense for some types but not others, it makes sense to prevent it being instantiated for the others.    For example, if a templated capability is only meaningful for numeric types, prevent it being instantiated for non-numeric types.   How you enforce that limitation may or may not be bad style though.   For example, how you decide to check at compile time if a type is "numeric".

Comment: @HenriMenke: I'm afraid C++17 won't have them yet. That's also explained on the very Wikipedia page you've linked to: *"During the C++ standards committee meeting in March 2016, the evolution working group moved to merge Concepts into the mainline C++17 standard, but the motion was defeated in full committee."*

Answer (score 2):

As written, your code will fail to compile if `Foo` is ever instantiated. For any type `T` that is not the same as `Bar`, the instantiation of `Foo<T>` will cause the instantiation of the return type of `Foo<T>::callFuncInBar`, which will fail. Likewise if `T` is not the same as `FooBar` then the instantiation of the return type of `callFuncInFooBar` will fail.

I assume this is not what you wanted.

I assume what you really wanted is for `Foo<T>::callFuncInBar` to only be callable when `T` is `Bar`. This is usually handled by template specialization: specialize the class template `Foo<T>` for `T` = `Bar` and `T` = `FooBar`, and in the primary template, do not declare the `callFuncInBar` and `callFuncInFooBar` member functions at all, so they will not be available. This avoids your style question entirely; `Foo` will be instantiable with any template argument, but with a feature set that depends on the particular argument. (And *that* is considered perfectly fine style-wise; even the standard library does it.)